# How to Export Data to Excel Using React Libraries and table antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to export an antdesign table, like this one **Editable Cells** `https://ant.design/components/table` to an excel file. I've done some research but haven't found anything similar.

thanks :)

I tried to follow this code `https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-excel-teedu`, which is amazing, however, in my table the dataSource and Columns are called inside the function App(), and the error appears: 'Uncaught TypeError: props.children.reduce is not a function'

**the extensions:
npm i better-xlsx,
npm i file-saver,
npm i antd-table-saveas-excel.**

TableExcel.js

```
import { Table, Drawer, Tooltip, Popconfirm, Button } from "antd";
import { RiFileExcel2Line } from 'react-icons/ri';
import { DeleteOutlined, FolderOpenOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import DrawerDB from "../../Drawer/DrawerDB";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Excel } from "antd-table-saveas-excel";

export default function TableExcel() {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const showDrawer = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };
    const onClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([
        {
            key: "1",
            id: 156,
            name: "Emily",
            age: 32,
            address: "10 Downing Street"
        },
        {
            key: "2",
            id: 336,
            name: "Joana",
            age: 42,
            address: "10 Downing Street"
        },
        {
            key: "3",
            id: 2398,
            name: "Maria",
            age: 42,
            address: "10 Downing Street"
        }
    ])

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newData = dataSource.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        setDataSource(newData);
    };

    const columns = [
        {
            key: '4',
            title: 'Abrir',
            dataIndex: 'abrir',
            width: 80,
            render: (record) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <button onClick={showDrawer}>
                            <FolderOpenOutlined />
                        </button>
                    </>
                )

            }
        },
        {
            key: '5',
            title: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            ellipsis: true,
            width: 80,
            filters: [
                {
                    text: 'London',
                    value: 'London',
                },
                {
                    text: 'New York',
                    value: 'New York',
                },
            ],
            onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.indexOf(value) === 0,
        },
        {
            key: '6',
            title: 'name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            ellipsis: true,
            width: 150,
            filters: [
                {
                    text: 'London',
                    value: 'London',
                },
                {
                    text: 'New York',
                    value: 'New York',
                },
            ],
            onFilter: (value, record) => record.name.indexOf(value) === 0,
        },

        {
            key: '7',
            title: 'age',
            dataIndex: 'age',
            ellipsis: true,
            width: 150,
            filters: [
                {
                    text: 'London',
                    value: 'London',
                },
                {
                    text: 'New York',
                    value: 'New York',
                },
            ],
            onFilter: (value, record) => record.age.indexOf(value) === 0,
        },

        {
            key: '8',
            title: 'Address',
            dataIndex: 'address',
            ellipsis: true,
            width: 100,

            render: (address) => (
                <Tooltip placement="topLeft" title={address}>
                    {address}
                </Tooltip>
            ),
            filters: [
                {
                    text: 'London',
                    value: 'London',
                },
                {
                    text: 'New York',
                    value: 'New York',
                },
            ],
            onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.indexOf(value) === 0,
        },

        {
            key: '9',

            title: 'Deletar',
            dataIndex: 'operation',
            render: (_, record) =>
                dataSource.length >= 0 ? (
                    <Popconfirm title="Tem certeza que deseja deletar?" cancelText='Cancelar' onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record.id)}>
                        <button><DeleteOutlined style={{ color: 'red', marginLeft: 15 }} /></button>
                    </Popconfirm>
                ) : null,

            width: 150,

        }

    ]

    const onChange = (pagination, filters, sorter, extra) => {
        console.log('params', pagination, filters, sorter, extra);
    };

    
        const handleClick = () => {
          const excel = new Excel();
          excel
            .addSheet("test")
            .addColumns(columns)
            .addDataSource(dataSource, {
              str2Percent: true
            })
            .saveAs("Excel.xlsx");
        };
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="export-excel">
                <Button className='btn' onClick={handleClick} >
                    <RiFileExcel2Line />
                </Button>
            </div>
            <Table
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={dataSource}
                style={{ padding: 35 }}
            >
            </Table>

            <Drawer width={1100} title="Informações completas" placement="right" onClose={onClose} open={open}>
                <DrawerDB />
            </Drawer>
        </>
    )
}
```

excel.js

```
import { File } from 'better-xlsx';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

function exportExcel(column, dataSource, fileName = 'example') {
  //  new working spectrum 
  const file = new File();
  //  the new table 
  let sheet = file.addSheet('sheet-test');
  //  gets the number of header rows 
  let depth = getDepth(column);
  //  gets the number of columns in the header 
  let columnNum = getColumns(column);
  //  new number of header rows 
  let rowArr = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < depth; k++) {
    rowArr.push(sheet.addRow());
  }
  //  populate the cells according to the number of columns 
  rowArr.map(ele => {
    for (let j = 0; j < columnNum; j++) {
      let cell = ele.addCell();
      cell.value = j;
    }
  });
  //  initializes the header 
  init(column, 0, 0);
  //  unfold the columns in order 
  let columnLineArr = [];
  columnLine(column);
  //  according to the column, the dataSource the data inside is sorted and converted into a two-dimensional array 
  let dataSourceArr = [];
  dataSource.map(ele => {
    let dataTemp = [];
    columnLineArr.map(item => {
      dataTemp.push({
        [item.dataIndex]: ele[item.dataIndex],
        value: ele[item.dataIndex],
      });
    });
    dataSourceArr.push(dataTemp);
  });
  // debugger;
  //  drawing table data 
  dataSourceArr.forEach((item, index) => {
    // according to the data, create the corresponding number of rows 
    let row = sheet.addRow();
    row.setHeightCM(0.8);
    // creates a cell for that number 
    item.map(ele => {
      let cell = row.addCell();
      if (ele.hasOwnProperty('num')) {
        cell.value = index + 1;
      } else {
        cell.value = ele.value;
      }
      cell.style.align.v = 'center';
      cell.style.align.h = 'center';
    });
  });
  // set the width of each column 
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sheet.col(i).width = 20;
  }
  file.saveAs('blob').then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, fileName + '.xlsx');
  });

  //  unfold the columns in order 
  function columnLine(column) {
    column.map(ele => {
      if (ele.children === undefined || ele.children.length === 0) {
        columnLineArr.push(ele);
      } else {
        columnLine(ele.children);
      }
    });
  }
  //  initializes the header 
  function init(column, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
    column.map((item, index) => {
      let hCell = sheet.cell(rowIndex, columnIndex);
      //  if there are no child elements,   all the columns 
      if (item.title === ' operation ') {
        hCell.value = '';
        return;
      } else if (item.children === undefined || item.children.length === 0) {
        //  add a cell to the first row 
        hCell.value = item.title;
        hCell.vMerge = depth - rowIndex - 1;
        hCell.style.align.h = 'center';
        hCell.style.align.v = 'center';
        columnIndex++;
        // rowIndex++
      } else {
        let childrenNum = 0;
        function getColumns(arr) {
          arr.map(ele => {
            if (ele.children) {
              getColumns(ele.children);
            } else {
              childrenNum++;
            }
          });
        }
        getColumns(item.children);
        hCell.hMerge = childrenNum - 1;
        hCell.value = item.title;
        hCell.style.align.h = 'center';
        hCell.style.align.v = 'center';
        let rowCopy = rowIndex;
        rowCopy++;
        init(item.children, rowCopy, columnIndex);
        //  next cell start 
        columnIndex = columnIndex + childrenNum;
      }
    });
  }
  //  gets table head rows 
  function getDepth(arr) {
    const eleDepths = [];
    arr.forEach(ele => {
      let depth = 0;
      if (Array.isArray(ele.children)) {
        depth = getDepth(ele.children);
      }
      eleDepths.push(depth);
    });
    return 1 + max(eleDepths);
  }

  function max(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((accu, curr) => {
      if (curr > accu) return curr;
      return accu;
    });
  }
  //  calculates the number of header columns 
  function getColumns(arr) {
    let columnNum = 0;
    arr.map(ele => {
      if (ele.children) {
        getColumns(ele.children);
      } else {
        columnNum++;
      }
    });
    return columnNum;
  }
}

export default exportExcel;
```

Comment: Can you please add your code snippets to the question. It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the code in this case.

Comment: @PavelSavva, sorry, i added my code :)